# Loading large amount of binary data into a `[B` in raw JVM bytecode

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

I am generating JVM bytecode in [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) syntax to load a large binary blob into a `[B`. The point is to have all the actual data stored in the `.class` file instead of reading it at runtime from an external source.

The code I have generated looks like this:

```
.method public static loadImage : ([B)V
  .code stack 6 locals 1
    aload_0
    iconst_0
    iconst_1
    iadd
    dup2
    bipush 71
    bastore
    iconst_1
    iadd
    dup2
    bipush 108
    bastore
    ...
    iconst_1
    iadd
    dup2
    bipush 0
    bastore
    return
  .end code
.end method
```

However, at runtime this method fails because it's too long:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: 
Invalid method Code length 572931 in class file Image
```

Is there a better way to load a large binary blob into a byte array? I guess one workaround would be to keep my current code, but split it into several methods, but that is quite horrible...

Comment: "The point is to have all the actual data stored in the .class file instead of reading it at runtime from an external source.", but why - what are the benefits versus using an embedded resource?

Comment: @user3707125: "Embedded resource"? What do you mean by that? That sounds a lot like what I'd need.

Comment: the thing that Peter Lawrey described in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a static field on your class, which is statically initialised by reading a resource. I use Guava ByteStreams below, use any io utils you like though...

```
class MyClass {
    static byte[] theData; 
    static {
        try { 
            theData = ByteStreams.toByteArray(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('/myBigResource.dat'))
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
     ...
}
```

You incur the cost of reading the secondary resource exactly once, at class loading time, but you would get that anyway even if you had the byte data embedded in your .class file. The only real extra cost you get is locating and opening that one extra resource, plus whatever object-interactions are involved in that.

The only real problem is the exception handling. If reading the resource throws an IOException that will appear in your program as a ClassNotFound exception, which can be confusing.

You also need to be aware that this is going to search your classpath for the resource file. Somebody could put a 'similarly' named file somewhere and create havoc. Particularly if it's a VeryLarge file.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is likely to be to store the data in a file which is distributed with the JAR load it into that.

If you really must store data in a class file which is really designed for code, you can store the data in a String in ISO-8859-1 format and call `string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")`